# Why does my WPF button require 2 clicks to invoke?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, button, click

I have a very simple WPF window, with a `Calendar` control and a `Button`. If I select (single-click) a date in the `Calendar` and then immediately single-click the `Button`, its `Command` is not executed. Only after I single-click the button a second time is the button Command invoked. (I notice that only after I click the button once will a mouse-over change the color of the button.) How can I get the (expected) behavior of not requiring 2 clicks to get the button to "work"?  (using .NET 4.6.1)

Comment: Is it a RelayCommand? do you have any condition on the command to be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add following code to your `Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged` event:

```
Mouse.Capture(null);
```